# Virtual Tape Libraries for Microsoft Data Protection Manager - Replacement for Crystalink Firestreamer?

Tags: windows, backup, virtualization, tape, scdpm

What VTLs do you all use to allow DPM to store off-site?

My current environment uses Microsoft DPM for all of its backups.  DPM stores the backups locally just fine, but to get it to store digital copies offsite we had been using Crystalink's "Firestreamer" to allow us to use a UNC path to some space we rent outside of our local network.

Firestreamer's not supported anymore, so I am hunting up a replacement - unfortunately I am coming up pretty dry as it seems like every viable Windows 2019-compatible VTL solution is also cloud integrated or part of a whole backup solution - something our management doesn't want as that offsite storage we're currently using is part of an existing connection agreement (and DPM is much cheaper than any of its replacements).

This is a relative weak spot for me as I did not configure the DPM setup we currently have, so I may not be homing in on the right keywords.  What's an alternative to Firestreamer that just offers up a VTL so I can toss backup files onto another device I have access to?

Answer (score 4):

StarWind VTL hands down! You can use local disks, you can offload to public cloud (AWS, Azure, and B2) or you can combine both approaches. Highly recommended! We use it with Veeam CE which can’t tier to S3 due to the license restrictions and we backup our IBM AS/400 and AIX boxes with it as well.

https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-tape-library

Comment: Thanks; that is one company I reached out to but have not yet heard back from.  They made the cloud component loud and clear, but there were only hints that it could be done in a purely locally networked context.  So there is a flavor of it that does allow it to send backups to some UNC path you've got mapped?

Comment: We use it with inexpensive SSDs, no cloud. It can be used as an AWS Gateway replacement, but it’s a totally different use case.